# Git Rebase issue while pushing changes to remote

Tags: git

Below is the problem:
I created branch `branch-1` from `master`.

Both branches are being updated by other users too.

Now `master` has **MC1**, **MC2** commits and `branch-1` has **B1C1**, **B1C2** commits(created by me).

A PR created and **B1C1** and **B1C2** got merged to master.

Some more changes in `master` **MC3** after this.

I rebased the `branch-1` with master. Successful.

`git fetch` and `git status` tells you have divergent branch.

Now if I do `git pull --rebase` from `branch-1` remote. Successful.

Now I pushed them to remote `branch-1` and checking by creating a PR.

PR is showing **B1C1'**, **B1C2'**, **MC3'** as commits that needs to be merged in `master`.

**What should be done here so that I dont see these commits as new?**

I understand that I could have done `git push -f`.

But that will be problematic if remote `branch-1` has changes from other user. Then definitely I would have to do first `pull --rebase` and then push.

Comment: I understand how `master` can have other commits, but if you created `branch-1` how can it have commits created by others?

Comment: Also you should not be keeping a branch around after it is merged. As soon as `branch-1` was originally merged to `master`, that should have been the _end_ of `branch-1` — you should have deleted it. Then you would not be having any of these issues.

Comment: I agree with both the above points.
But this is how it is. We have a branch other than master which is going to stay for sometime with multiple folks working together on that other branch.

Answer (score 0):

Don't rebase. This branch has already been pushed and merged; rebasing after that is (as you've discovered) a Really Bad Idea.

If the goal is to move the merge-base higher along `master` (and check for possible conflicts), simply reverse merge `master` into `branch-1`. A commit already on `master` will then not appear in the PR, because it is already on `master`; the reason it appeared after the rebase is that rebases replace commits with different ones.

And may I strongly advise you never to say `git pull`, as it is nondeterministic. Say `git fetch` and then do whatever it is you want to do. In this case that would be `git merge origin/master`.

And may I suggest that if you have a local `master`, you should delete it. Everything you need to do with `master` can be done with `origin/master` instead.

Comment: thanks @matt .
Instead of doing `git merge origin/master` in current situation, I observed that `git rebase master` has restored my branch to the point before `git pull --rebase` step. So I am out of trouble for now. But what I understood that if you really want to preserve the hx of master and then apply your changes then you dont do rebase from tracked remote.

Only problem with merge is that it creates a merge commit. Which I am not sure on how to squash with my previous changes

Comment: I don't see why that's a problem. I do this sort of thing every day and I'm feeling fine. :) But then, I don't feel compelled to squash either.

Comment: agree, but you know already set standards of team. They dont want to see multiple commits in PR, there should only be 1 final commit(squash all of your commit).

Comment: Well, that's interesting but it wasn't in the original question.